# Should I rollback?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rollbacks

An edit introduced nothing but a bunch of useless code formats. I and another user rejected it as too minor, but there were three approves first.

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24821828/revisions

Should I rollback edits like these, even if they're more "useless" than actively detrimental?

Answer (score 3):

Rolling back now will not improve anything since the edit does not hurt.

But you could leave a nice hint for the editor and explain to him why and how he could avoid minor edits in the future.

Comment: Leave a comment for him.

Comment: Where? In the post they edited?

Comment: @kviiri you can @-notify the user with a comment to the question, as he's now part of the revision history. Regarding "the edit does not hurt", I'm not a native speaker but replacing "I have andoid code" with "I've android code" feels wrong for me...

Comment: @l4mpi, that's true. I guess it's rollback-worthy after all.

Comment: Also, adding code formatting (or other formatting) to seemingly random words hurts legibility. Code formatting is used for **code**. Not keywords.